# working with nested for loop with if statment

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a data frame of two columns first is the longitude and second is the latitude. I want to find the coordinates of the center cell.
e.g. the range is lat[31 31.5], lon[33 33.5] if the first values of two columns fulfill this condition then create the third column and put the value 31.25 and create the fourth column and put in it the value 33.25

I have tried nested for loop but it does not work

```
# my dataframe is cycle8 contain 166 rows and two columns
latitude<- seq(31,37,by=0.5)
longitude<- seq(33,37,by=0.5)
cycle8$latcenter<- 0
cycle8$loncenter<-0
for (m in 1:nrow(cycle8)) 
{
  for(j in seq_along(latitude))
  {
    for(k in seq_along(longitude))
    {    
      if (cycle8$lat[m]>=j && cycle8$lat[m]<=j+0.5 && cycle8$lon[m]>=k && 
          cycle8$lon[m]<=k+0.5)
      {
        cycle8$latcenter[m]<- j+0.25

        cycle8$loncenter[m]<- k+0.25
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

[image: my data frame]
[image: Expected results]

## the following code will work and deliver the desired result but it is so long and requires a lot of statement typing

```
cycle8$latcenter<- 0

for (m in 1:nrow(cycle8)) 
{

   if (cycle8$lat[m]>=31 && cycle8$lat[m]<=31.5 )
   {
     cycle8$latcenter[m]<- 31+0.25
   }
     else if
       (cycle8$lat[m]>=31.5 && cycle8$lat[m]<=32 ){
       cycle8$latcenter[m]<- 31.5+0.25
     }
     else if
       (cycle8$lat[m]>=32 && cycle8$lat[m]<=32.5 ){
       cycle8$latcenter[m]<- 32+0.25
     }
     else if
       (cycle8$lat[m]>=32.5 && cycle8$lat[m]<=33 ){
       cycle8$latcenter[m]<- 32.5+0.25
     }
     else if
       (cycle8$lat[m]>=33 && cycle8$lat[m]<=33.5 ){
       cycle8$latcenter[m]<- 33+0.25
     }
     else if
       (cycle8$lat[m]>=33.5 && cycle8$lat[m]<=34 ){
       cycle8$latcenter[m]<- 33.5+0.25
     }
     else if
       (cycle8$lat[m]>=34 && cycle8$lat[m]<=34.5 ){
       cycle8$latcenter[m]<- 34+0.25
     }
     else if
       (cycle8$lat[m]>=34.5 && cycle8$lat[m]<=35 ){
       cycle8$latcenter[m]<- 34.5+0.25
     }
     else if
       (cycle8$lat[m]>=35 && cycle8$lat[m]<=35.5 ){
       cycle8$latcenter[m]<- 35+0.25
     }
     else if
       (cycle8$lat[m]>=35.5 && cycle8$lat[m]<=36 ){
       cycle8$latcenter[m]<- 35.5+0.25
     }
     else if
       (cycle8$lat[m]>=36 && cycle8$lat[m]<=36.5 ){
       cycle8$latcenter[m]<- 36+0.25
     }
     else if
       (cycle8$lat[m]>=36.5 && cycle8$lat[m]<=37 ){
       cycle8$latcenter[m]<- 36.5+0.25
     }
    }
```

Comment: In your example there are lat values outside of [31 31.5] but the expected output rounds them as you describe for values that meet this condition. So to me it seems like you simply want to round by .25?

Comment: in my code, I have added the data frame "cycle8", I have 166 values of latitude and 166 values of longitude. I want to do ranging if those latitudes and longitudes belong to the range then I want to create new columns contain values of  the center of the range

Comment: I only here uploaded the first ten rows, the rest of rows contains more values of lon and latI want to check the following ranges  lat [31 31.5], [31.5 32], [32 32.5], [32.5 34] and so on till [36.5 37] and similarly for lon [33 33.5] and so on till [36.5 37]

Comment: the question to be more clear, I will explain to you. the first value of the column lon is 33.350407 I want to write code that checks at which range this value belong here it belongs to [33 33.5] and then put in new column the value of the center of this range which is 33.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution avoids for-loops, sapply or other similiar functions. The logic behind the code is as follows: Since the ranges have decimals .50 or .00, the centered values will always be .25 or .75. This means that we simply need to replace the decimals; all decimals between .00 and.50 become.25, while the other ones become .75.

Here the code for this

```
# generate data
latitude <- seq(30, 32, .1)
longitude <- seq(30, 32, .1)
cycle8 <- data.frame(latitude, longitude)

# make a function that replaces decimals as explained above
lat_lon <- function(vec){
decimals <- as.character(format(vec, nsmall= 1))
decimals <- as.numeric(gsub("^.*\\.", "", decimals))
decimals <- ifelse(decimals < 5, .25, .75)
values <- as.numeric(gsub("\\..*","",vec)) + as.numeric(decimals)
return(values)
}

# apply function
cycle8$lat_center <- lat_lon(latitude)
cycle8$lon_center <- lat_lon(longitude)

# see results
cycle8
```

**EDIT**

Because you want 30.00 to be 29.75 and 30.50 to be 30.25, here is an edit. But the logic remains the same.

```
latitude <- seq(30, 32, .1)
longitude <- seq(30, 32, .1)
cycle8 <- data.frame(latitude, longitude)
lat_lon <- function(vec){
decimals <- as.character(format(vec, nsmall= 1))
decimals <- as.numeric(gsub("^.*\\.", "", decimals))
decimals_new <- ifelse(decimals > 5 | decimals == 0, .75, .25)
values <- as.numeric(gsub("\\..*","",vec)) + as.numeric(decimals_new)
values[decimals == 0] <- values[decimals == 0] - 1
return(values)
}
cycle8$lat_center <- lat_lon(latitude)
cycle8$lon_center <- lat_lon(longitude)
cycle8
```

Comment: no not like that,  the cycle8 contains values of lon and lat with decimal , and the values latitude<- seq(31,37,by=0.1) and  longitude<- seq(33,37,by=0.1) are the ranges. I want to create a grid and check the values which fill in the same cell and then do futher processes.

Comment: Ok, I don't get it. Maybe someone else can help!

Comment: thanks anyway at least you have tried to help. but I will clarify it more. apart from this code, suppose that I have a value of  10.23 in th first row and I have a range [10 10.5] the question is  to check if 10.23 belongs to this range or not if yes  then create a new column and put in it the value of (10+10.5)/2 which is 10.25 or else check the second reange e.g. [10.5 11] and so on. now move to second row which contain e.g. the value 10.56 and do the check again untill we finish all the rows of first column.

Comment: @Jisika: my code will return exactly that: round(10.23/.25)*.25 returns 10.25, for example. The code above should always give results you look for (unless there are special cases I don't know of). Did you try it and observe any unexpected results?

Comment: it does not work e.g. for the value 33.57776  the result of your code is 33.5 but my desired result should be 33.75 as 33.57776 belongs to [33.5 34]

Comment: @Jisika ok. What is the expected result for 35.00? Is it 34.75 or 35.25? And what is the expected result for 35.50? Is it 35.25 or 35.75?

Comment: 35 should be 34.75 and 35.5 should be 35.25

Comment: @Jisika: Happy to hear that. Consider marking my post as answer/ voting up since this is how this website works

Answer (score 0):

```
# The other way of solving this question is 
mydata<- c(35.666,35.4578,35.0, 33.50,32.10)
centered_value <- function(val){ 
                               a<- trunc(val)
                               b<- val %% 1
 c<- ifelse(b/0.5 > 1, a +0.75 , ifelse(b/0.5> 1, a+0.25, ifelse(b/0.5 ==0, a- 
                                                                      0.25,a+0.25)))
                               }
       d<- centered_value(mydata)
       d
```